# How to remove brackets in NSMutableArray in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a mutable array contains array at each index in it. This is code for I get Mutable array values from NSUserdefaults.

```
productsMutArr = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "PRODUCTSMUTARRAY") as! NSMutableArray
    if (productsMutArr.count != 0) {
        print("productsMutArr :",productsMutArr)
    }
```

And the Response is:

```
productsMutArr : (
    {
    id = 30;
    name = Pedicure;
    price = "13.00";
    "price Symbol" = "$";
})
```

Here I want to get Name into a new Mutable array so I use this following code:

```
productNameMutArray.add(productsMutArr.value(forKey: "name"))
```

Now my new Name Mutable array looks like this:

```
productNameMutArray : (
    (
    Pedicure
) )
```

Here I want to add more Names in Name mutable array so i added then it look like this:

```
MutArray is: (
    (
    Pedicure
    )
    (
    full
    )
    )
```

but I want to make a single array of that like this format:

```
MutArray is: (
    Pedicure
    full
    )
```

How can I remove (),() inside the array and make a single array containing the objects?

Comment: Use Swift `Array` and `.map`. `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift is very bad anyway.

Comment: ...This doesn't look like Swift.

Comment: How, Can you please explain?@vadian

Comment: This is pure swift, Just I show the Response only.@PedroCastilho

Comment: @saravanaKumarB Please post the actual code instead of just the response.  It's really unclear, especially since you're using parentheses instead of brackets.

Comment: No, it is not working@NiravD

Answer (score 1):

Try using Array.flatMap:

```
let array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
let new_array = array.flatMap { $0 }
print(new_array)
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3.0 :**

suppose I have arrays like this.

```
var array1 = ["array1Element1","array1Element2","array1Element3"]
var array2 = ["array2Element1","array2Element2","array2Element3"]
```

If I want array of above array i.e. **masterArray**

```
var masterArray = [array1,array2]
```

In **Swift** **let** is used for immutable variables and **var** is used for mutable variale.

Comment: I'm not downvoting since the question is so unclear, but I think this is the opposite of what they want.

Comment: Sometimes we need to understand questions. As some guys are not able to    express question in well manner. But thanks